# Configuring ADC in STM32F3

Tags: adc, stm32f3

I'm trying to enable an ADC converter. I'm using STM32F3 Discovery with SPL Library. I measure voltage on PA1 pin. I don't know why it doesn't work. What have I missed? The value of 'value' variable doesn't change and equals 0.

```
#include "stm32f30x.h"
#include "stm32f30x_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f30x_adc.h"
#include <stm32f30x_gpio.h>


uint16_t Read_ADC()
{
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_2, 1, ADC_SampleTime_4Cycles5);
    ADC_StartConversion(ADC1);
    while(ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1,ADC_FLAG_EOC)==RESET);
    return ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1);
}

void delay_ms (int time)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < time * 4000; i++) {}
}

int main()
{

  uint16_t value = 0;

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_InitStructure;
  ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStructure;

  RCC_ADCCLKConfig(RCC_ADC12PLLCLK_Div2);
  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE); //PA1 ADC1_IN2
  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOE, ENABLE);

  GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin  = LED;
  GPIO_Init( GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);
  uint32_t led = 0;

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_8b;
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStructure);
  ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);


  while(1)
      {
          value = Read_ADC();
      }
}
```

Comment: Put some dwell in your while loop, so any debugger has time to update.  It's probably not your answer, but it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Previously I had code in the while loop responsible for turning led diodes and It didn't work as well

Comment: Did you checke whether the clock to the SDC is enabled somewhere? It is probably off by default.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen  -- there are RCC commands in the code (though without looking, I don't know if they're right!)

Comment: It looks like the GPIO clock is enabled, but not the ADC clock

Comment: @ScottSeidman ADC in this uCs has two clocks. Enablink one is not enough

Comment: RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_ADC12, ENABLE);

Comment: 90-95% of the time, this is a failure to turn the clocks on.

Answer (score 1):

I got something like this

```
#include "stm32f30x.h"
#include "stm32f30x_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f30x_adc.h"
#include <stm32f30x_gpio.h>

#define LED (GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 | GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15)

uint16_t convertedValue= 0;

void delay_ms (int time)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < time * 4000; i++) {}
}

void Configure_ADC(void)
{
    RCC_ADCCLKConfig(RCC_ADC12PLLCLK_Div2);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_ADC12,ENABLE);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin  = GPIO_Pin_1;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIO_InitStructure);

    ADC_DeInit(ADC1);
    ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_InitStructure;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_10b;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEvent = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEvent_0;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfRegChannel = 1;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigEventEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigEventEdge_None;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ADC_ContinuousConvMode_Enable;
    ADC_Init(ADC1,&ADC_InitStructure);
    ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
}

uint16_t Read_ADC()
{
    while(!ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_RDY));
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_2, 1,    ADC_SampleTime_1Cycles5);
    ADC_StartConversion(ADC1);
    while(ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1,ADC_FLAG_EOC)==RESET);
    return ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1);
}

int main()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOE, ENABLE);
    GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin  = LED;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    uint32_t led = 0;


    while(1)
      {

          convertedValue = Read_ADC();//Read the ADC converted value
          GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, 1 << led); //turn on a diode
          delay_ms(150); // wait
          GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, 1 << led); //turn off a diode
          if (++led >= 16)
              {
                  led = 8;
              }
      }
}
```

I've configured according to manual. Program stops on Read_ADC function.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't enabled the ADC clock.  Try

```
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_ADC12, ENABLE);
```

If that doesn't work, use your IDE to find the declaration of RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd and read the source to see if I've gotten the name of the clock wrong.

The [STM30xx library docs](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/d1/02/f0/b6/1a/8a/43/de/DM00068049.pdf/files/DM00068049.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00068049.pdf)  will probably be of help.  Enabling the ADC clock is step 2 in Section 3.2.1 -- and I can't see anything else you missed.  From that doc:

> 3.2.1 How to use this driver
>
> 1. select the ADC clock using the function RCC_ADCCLKConfig()
> 2. Enable the ADC interface clock using RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd();
> 3. ADC pins configuration  Enable the clock for the ADC GPIOs using the following function: RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOx,
>    ENABLE);  Configure these ADC pins in analog mode using GPIO_Init();
> 4. Configure the ADC conversion resolution, data alignment, external trigger and edge, sequencer lenght and Enable/Disable the continuous
>    mode using the ADC_Init() function.
> 5. Activate the ADC peripheral using ADC_Cmd() function.
>    FWIW, when I have trouble, I usually go into the library declarations, as these functions tend to be very well self-documented.

FWIW, my SOP for library problems is to find the declaration in the library, as the libraries tend to be fairly well self-documented.

Comment: I have done it according to the manual but still doesn't work. I placed my fixed code above